# allauth account edit in django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am building an application with django and I decided to opt for the allauth authentication. now I have a profile page and I want users to be able to edit their account to Include Bios, Last_name ,first_name and thingx like that and possibly include a display picture but I inplemented some codes and I got an error an I have been stocked at it for a long time. the Error is

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/src/profiles/models.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Profile(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 331, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    raise TypeError("'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): %s" % ','.join(meta_attrs.keys()))
TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): fields,model
```

**model.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=125)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=125)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from profiles.models import Profile

class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

That is my code above with the erro and I just can not get to wrap my head around what the problem is.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove attrs

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ... your code here
    class Meta: # And this line need to remove
        model = User # And this line need to remove
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name') # this line need to remove
```

in Model meta you can use only [models options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/)

If you want to extend the default django user model, read the [auth customizing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Comment: so there should be no Meta in the model

Comment: i got the following error  'TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): model'

Comment: I simply removed the fields. and the `TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): model` came up

Comment: I edit the answer, in your case need remove class META

Comment: Ok it works now but if I want to add more fields like Bios and picture upload option . Do I just add the field into the profile model?

Comment: Add link to the answer for customize user models

Comment: please I got the following error in my browser `Exception Value:  

global name 'UpdateProfile' is not defined`

Comment: you need add import the `UpdateProfile` in the place were you catch the error

Comment: yeah I did that and it fine. then another error saying `global name 'RegistrationForm' is not defined`  then I imported it to my view and I got this error `from .forms import RegistrationForm
ImportError: cannot import name RegistrationForm`

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

does not belong in your model. Hence, both `model` and `fields` are invalid keyword arguments for your model's `Meta` class.

EDIT to respond to comments:

If you want to add more fields, you would add them on your model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_new_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, in your model form, add `my_new_field` into the `fields` parameter. Note that unless you want to do something beyond what your model is providing, you only need to add this to the `tuple` of fields. In other words, you do not need to add:

```
my_new_field = forms.IntegerField()
```

`ModelForm` handles this magically for you, as shown in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

This is the advantage of using things like model forms and model viewsets. It keeps your code DRY by re-using the schema of your model, inferring the fields and field types.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Ok it works now but if I want to add more fields like Bios and picture upload option . Do I just add the field into the profile model?

Comment: thanks. please I got the following error in my browser` Exception Value: global name 'UpdateProfile' is not defined`

Comment: We would need more information to troubleshoot that, but I would hazard to guess that you forgot to import that class?

Comment: yeah I did that and it fine. then another error saying  `global name 'RegistrationForm' ` is not defined then I imported it to my view and I got this error  `from .forms import RegistrationForm ImportError: cannot import name RegistrationForm`

Comment: Does that class exist in your `forms.py`?

Comment: no it does not but I am using allauth so I simply assumed it is a predefined class

Answer (score 1):

For your last error need to replace

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        #           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UpdateProfile, self).save(commit=False)
        #           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

more details [working-python-super-function](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function)

Comment: Thanks I cant believe I made such an error which occured when I was trying to fix previous errors